# Transforming NodaTime ZoneIntervals

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

Version 2 may be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237100/transforming-nodatime-zoneintervals-version-2).

The company I work for has customers around the globe.  I work with a time-series database that contains manufacturing process data for each customer site.  I was asked to provide daily averages for the past 2 years.  Requesting averages from the 3rd party time-series database is easy.  The difficulty is that each request needs to be issued specific for each site's time zone.

NodaTime's ZoneInterval provides me *some* information, but I need to transform it for my 3rd party database.  The calls to the time series database expects start and end times in UTC, and you may ask for the summaries to be returned in evenly spaced TimeSpan intervals - think hours here not a "day".  This is easy enough for most days during the year except for any DST transition days where the day length is not 24 hours.

Here is the **ZonedDateRange.cs** class used to perform the custom transformation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.TimeZones;

namespace NodaTime_Zoned_Ranges
{
    public class ZonedDateRange
    {
        public enum DayState { Standard, DST, SpringForward, FallBack }

        public DateTimeZone Zone { get; private set; }
        public DayState State { get; private set; }
        public LocalDate StartDay { get; private set; }
        public LocalDate EndDay { get; private set; }

        public ZonedDateTime ZoneStart => Zone.AtStartOfDay(StartDay);
        public ZonedDateTime ZoneEnd => Zone.AtStartOfDay(EndDay.PlusDays(1));

        public DateTime UtcStart => ZoneStart.ToDateTimeUtc();
        public DateTime UtcEnd => ZoneEnd.ToDateTimeUtc();

        public double HoursPerDay => IsTransitionDay ? (UtcEnd - UtcStart).TotalHours : 24;

        public int DaysInRange => IsTransitionDay ? 1 : (int)((ZoneStart - ZoneEnd).TotalDays);


        // -1 = Falling back DAY, +1 Spring Forward DAY, 0 means no transition occuring BUT the day still could be DST.
        public int Transition => (State == DayState.FallBack) ? Backward : (State == DayState.SpringForward) ? Forward : None;
        public bool IsTransitionDay => (Transition != None);

        public const int Backward = -1;
        public const int Forward = 1;
        public const int None = 0;

        // Private constructor forces using static factory.
        private ZonedDateRange() { }

        // A list should be fairly small.  Consider U.S. Central Time for an entire calendar year.  There will only be 5 items in the list.
        //      1) CST from Jan 1 to the day before Spring forward.
        //      2) Spring Forward transition day (one day is both start and end)
        //      3) CDT from day after Spring Forward and day before Fall Back.
        //      4) Fall Back transition day (again, only 1 day in range)
        //      5) CST after Fall Back day
        // The most important thing is that all days in a range will have the same length.
        // That way you can safely average in whatever that length is.

        public static IEnumerable<ZonedDateRange> GenerateRanges(DateTimeZone zone, Instant anchorInstant, int days)
        {
            if (zone == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(zone));
            }

            var anchorDay = anchorInstant.InZone(zone).Date;

            // If days is negative, anchorInstant is the endDay and we go back in time to get the start day.
            // Otherwise, anchorDay is the anchorInstant and we go forward in time to get the end day.
            var inclusiveStartDay = (days < 0) ? anchorDay.PlusDays(days) : anchorDay;
            var inclusiveEndDay = (days < 0) ? anchorDay : anchorDay.PlusDays(days);

            return GenerateRanges(zone, inclusiveStartDay, inclusiveEndDay);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ZonedDateRange> GenerateRanges(DateTimeZone zone, LocalDate inclusiveStartDay, LocalDate inclusiveEndDay)
        {
            if (zone == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(zone));
            }

            // Small adjustment to add an extra day to the inclusive end day.
            // When working with LocalDate(s) that are inclusive, we generally start at the start of the start day
            // but want to end at the END of the end day, which is really the start of the next day following the
            // end day.
            var exclusiveEndDay = inclusiveEndDay.PlusDays(1);

            var startInstant = inclusiveStartDay.AtStartOfDayInZone(zone).ToInstant();
            var endInstant = exclusiveEndDay.AtStartOfDayInZone(zone).ToInstant();

            // Just in case the start or end day occurs on transition day, we pad each endpoint with a few days.
            // We will later prune away this padding.
            var pad = Duration.FromDays(5);
            var padStartInstant = startInstant.Minus(pad);
            var padEndInstant = endInstant.Plus(pad);

            var intervals = zone.GetZoneIntervals(padStartInstant, padEndInstant).ToList();

            // Take care of easy cases.
            // Check count returned instead of custom SupportsDaylightSavingsTime method.
            // E.g. Argentina supported DST in the past, but since 2010 has been on Standard time only.
            if (intervals.Count == 1)
            {
                yield return Create(zone, inclusiveStartDay, exclusiveEndDay, DayState.Standard);
                yield break;
            }

            for (var index = 0; index < intervals.Count; index++)
            {
                var interval = ClampInterval(intervals[index], padStartInstant, padEndInstant);

                // Chop off the Start and End dates, since those are transition days.
                // That is move Start ahead 1 day, and move End back 1 day.
                var currStartDate = interval.Start.InZone(zone).Date.PlusDays(1);
                var currEndDate = interval.End.InZone(zone).Date.PlusDays(-1);

                var endLength = zone.HoursInDay(interval.End);

                var endState = DayState.Standard;
                if (endLength > NodaConstants.HoursPerDay)
                {
                    endState = DayState.FallBack;
                }
                else if (endLength < NodaConstants.HoursPerDay)
                {
                    endState = DayState.SpringForward;
                }

                var startState = (endState == DayState.FallBack) ? DayState.DST : DayState.Standard;
                var range = Create(zone, currStartDate, currEndDate, startState);
                AdjustEndPoints(range, inclusiveStartDay, exclusiveEndDay);
                if (IsOkayToOutput(range))
                {
                    yield return range;
                }

                var endTransitionDate = interval.End.InZone(zone).Date;
                range = Create(zone, endTransitionDate, endTransitionDate, endState);
                AdjustEndPoints(range, endTransitionDate, endTransitionDate);
                if (IsOkayToOutput(range))
                {
                    yield return range;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void AdjustEndPoints(ZonedDateRange range, LocalDate startDay, LocalDate endDay)
        {
            if (range.StartDay < startDay)
            {
                range.StartDay = startDay;
            }
            if (range.EndDay > endDay)
            {
                range.EndDay = endDay;
            }
        }

        private static bool IsOkayToOutput(ZonedDateRange range) => (range.UtcEnd > range.UtcStart);

        private static ZoneInterval ClampInterval(ZoneInterval interval, Instant start, Instant end)
        {
            var outstart = start;
            var outend = end;

            if (interval.HasStart && outstart < interval.Start)
            {
                outstart = interval.Start;
            }

            if (interval.HasEnd && interval.End < outend)
            {
                outend = interval.End;
            }

            return new ZoneInterval(interval.Name, outstart, outend, interval.WallOffset, interval.Savings);
        }

        private static ZonedDateRange Create(DateTimeZone zone, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, DayState state)
        {
            var range = new ZonedDateRange
            {
                Zone = zone,
                StartDay = startDate,
                EndDay = endDate,
                State = state
            };
            return range;
        }

        // This alters the StartDate and UtcStartTime so you may want to perform this on a Clone().
        internal void AdjustStartDateForward(LocalDate adjustedStartDate)
        {
            if (adjustedStartDate < StartDay || adjustedStartDate > EndDay)
            {
                throw new Exception($"The {nameof(adjustedStartDate)} must be exclusively within the current StartDate and EndDate.");
            }
            AdjustDates(adjustedStartDate, EndDay);
        }

        // This alters the EndDate and UtcEndTime so you may want to perform this on a Clone().
        internal void AdjustEndDateBackward(LocalDate adjustedEndDate)
        {
            if (adjustedEndDate < StartDay || adjustedEndDate > EndDay)
            {
                throw new Exception($"The {nameof(adjustedEndDate)} must be exclusively within the current StartDate and EndDate.");
            }
            AdjustDates(StartDay, adjustedEndDate);
        }

        private void AdjustDates(LocalDate adjustedStart, LocalDate adjustedEnd)
        {
            StartDay = adjustedStart;
            EndDay = adjustedEnd;
        }

        public ZonedDateRange Clone()
        {
            var clone = new ZonedDateRange();
            clone.Zone = Zone;
            clone.State = State;
            clone.StartDay = StartDay;
            clone.EndDay = EndDay;
            return clone;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the **Extensions.cs** class for a few convenient extensions:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

namespace NodaTime_Zoned_Ranges
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        // For DST Transition days, hours will be less than or greater than 24.
        public static double HoursInDay(this DateTimeZone zone, Instant instant)
        {
            if (zone == null)
            {
                return NodaConstants.HoursPerDay;
            }

            var day = instant.InZone(zone).LocalDateTime.Date;

            var bod = zone.AtStartOfDay(day);
            var eod = zone.AtStartOfDay(day.PlusDays(1));

            return (eod.ToInstant() - bod.ToInstant()).TotalHours;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Preferred format of ISO 8601 time string.  
        /// Unlike Round Trip format specifier of "o", this format will suppress decimal seconds
        /// if the input time does not have subseconds.
        /// </summary>
        public const string DateTimeExtendedIsoFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFK";


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an ISO-8601 compliant time string.  
        /// If the input Kind is Local and TimeZoneInfo.Local is not "UTC", then the output string will contain a time zone offset. 
        /// Unlike ToString("o"), if the input time does not contain subseconds, the output string will omit subseconds.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time">DateTime</param>
        /// <returns>String</returns>
        public static string ToIsoString(this DateTime time)
        {
            // TimeZoneInfo MUST use Equals method and not == operator.
            // Equals compares values where == compares object references.
            if (time.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local && TimeZoneInfo.Local.Equals(TimeZoneInfo.Utc))
            {
                // Don't use time zone offset if Local time is UTC
                time = DateTime.SpecifyKind(time, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
            return time.ToString(DateTimeExtendedIsoFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is **Program.cs** for some quick and dirty testing:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

namespace NodaTime_Zoned_Ranges
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var zoneIds = new string[] { "Central Brazilian Standard Time", "Singapore Standard Time" };

            var startDay = new LocalDate(2018, 1, 1);
            var endDay = new LocalDate(2019, 12, 31);

            foreach (var zoneId in zoneIds)
            {
                var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetZoneOrNull(zoneId);
                ZoneTest(zone, startDay, endDay);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress ENTER key");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ZoneTest(DateTimeZone zone, LocalDate startDay, LocalDate endDay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\n*** TEST FOR ZONE: {zone.Id} , Start:{startDay} , End:{endDay}\n");

            var startInstant = startDay.AtStartOfDayInZone(zone).ToInstant();
            var endInstant = endDay.PlusDays(1).AtStartOfDayInZone(zone).ToInstant();

            Console.WriteLine("NodaTime DateTimeZone.GetZoneIntervals");
            var intervals = zone.GetZoneIntervals(startInstant, endInstant);

            var i = 0;
            foreach (var interval in intervals)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  [{i++}]: {interval}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nCustom ZonedDateRange");
            i = 0;
            var ranges = ZonedDateRange.GenerateRanges(zone, startDay, endDay);
            foreach (var range in ranges)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  [{i++}]: {range.State,13}: [{range.UtcStart.ToIsoString()}, {range.UtcEnd.ToIsoString()}] HoursPerDay: {range.HoursPerDay}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is sample **Console Window output**:

```
*** TEST FOR ZONE: Central Brazilian Standard Time , Start:Monday, January 1, 2018 , End:Tuesday, December 31, 2019

NodaTime DateTimeZone.GetZoneIntervals
  [0]: Central Brazilian Daylight Time: [2017-10-15T03:59:59Z, 2018-02-18T02:59:59Z) -03 (+01)
  [1]: Central Brazilian Standard Time: [2018-02-18T02:59:59Z, 2018-11-04T03:59:59Z) -04 (+00)
  [2]: Central Brazilian Daylight Time: [2018-11-04T03:59:59Z, 2019-02-17T03:00:00Z) -03 (+01)
  [3]: Central Brazilian Standard Time: [2019-02-17T03:00:00Z, EndOfTime) -04 (+00)

Custom ZonedDateRange
  [0]:           DST: [2018-01-01T03:00:00Z, 2018-02-17T03:00:00Z] HoursPerDay: 24
  [1]:      FallBack: [2018-02-17T03:00:00Z, 2018-02-18T04:00:00Z] HoursPerDay: 25
  [2]:      Standard: [2018-02-18T04:00:00Z, 2018-11-04T03:59:59.999Z] HoursPerDay: 24
  [3]: SpringForward: [2018-11-04T03:59:59.999Z, 2018-11-05T03:00:00Z] HoursPerDay: 23.0000002777778
  [4]:           DST: [2018-11-05T03:00:00Z, 2019-02-16T03:00:00Z] HoursPerDay: 24
  [5]:      FallBack: [2019-02-16T03:00:00Z, 2019-02-17T04:00:00Z] HoursPerDay: 25
  [6]:      Standard: [2019-02-17T04:00:00Z, 2020-01-02T04:00:00Z] HoursPerDay: 24
  [7]:      Standard: [2020-01-06T04:00:00Z, 2020-01-07T04:00:00Z] HoursPerDay: 24


*** TEST FOR ZONE: Singapore Standard Time , Start:Monday, January 1, 2018 , End:Tuesday, December 31, 2019

NodaTime DateTimeZone.GetZoneIntervals
  [0]: Malay Peninsula Standard Time: [StartOfTime, EndOfTime) +08 (+00)

Custom ZonedDateRange
  [0]:      Standard: [2017-12-31T16:00:00Z, 2020-01-01T16:00:00Z] HoursPerDay: 24


Press ENTER key
```

Based on the output, I hope you can see why I need to perform the transform.  For Brazil, I can make 8 specific summary calls to my 3rd party database, each with differing UTC start and end times, as well as day length.  For Singapore, you can see I can get very specific UTC times from an interval that has no start or end time.

I have no specific question other than the always implied question of "Please review my code for readability and performance."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside: the zone intervals reported by Noda Time look somewhat broken to me; that may be due to them coming from the Windows time zone database. I'll need to look into that transitions don't happen on "the second before the start of the hour".

I haven't had time to look at this completely, but a few minor suggestions:

## Naming

You're using "day" a lot where I'd use "date". I find that less ambiguous, because a "day" can mean both a period and a date. I've adjusted the code below assuming that.

## GenerateRanges

```
var inclusiveStartDate = (days < 0) ? anchorDate.PlusDays(days) : anchorDate;
var inclusiveEndDate = (days < 0) ? anchorDate : anchorDate.PlusDays(days);
```

That would be simpler IMO as by adding `days` unconditionally and then just taking the min/max:

```
var anchorPlusDays = anchorDate.PlusDays(days);
var inclusiveStartDate = LocalDate.Min(anchorDate, anchorPlusDays);
var inclusiveEndDate = LocalDate.Max(anchorDate, anchorPlusDays);
```

## Extensions

I'd personally use separate extension classes for code using NodaTime types, and code using BCL types.

## AdjustEndpoints

I'd probably try to make your `ZonedDateRange` completely immutable (removing the need for `Clone`), and instead have `WithStartDate`, `WithEndDate` methods, then make `AdjustEndpoints` something like this:

```
private static ZonedDateRange AdjustEndPoints(
    ZonedDateRange range, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) =>
    range.WithStartDate(LocalDate.Max(range.StartDate, startDate))
         .WithEndDate(LocalDate.Min(range.EndDate, endDate));
```

(The `WithStartDate` and `WithEndDate` methods can return "this" if the argument is equal to the current value.)

Comment: Thanks for the review, Jon.  `Clone` is very important to me because I may have tens of thousands of instrument tags at a given plant site.  Though all have the same time zone, each tag may have recorded data with varying timestamps, thus I have to customize each tag's call with it's available start and end UTC time.  `GenerateRanges` feels a bit sluggish, and I don't want to recreate it thousands of times.

Comment: Version 2 is now immutable with better naming.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237100/transforming-nodatime-zoneintervals-version-2