# Transforming NodaTime ZoneIntervals, version 2

Tags: datetime, nodatime

Version 1 may be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236787/transforming-nodatime-zoneintervals).

I have implemented the suggestions by [Jon Skeet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16031/jon-skeet), plus some of my own.  Key differences between versions:

- ZonedDateRange class is now immutable.
- LocalDate variables no longer are named with "Day".
- Some ToString() methods were added.

**ZonedDateRange.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.TimeZones;

namespace NodaTime_Zoned_Ranges
{
    public class ZonedDateRange
    {
        public enum DayState { Standard, DST, SpringForward, FallBack }

        public DateTimeZone Zone { get; }
        public DayState State { get; }
        public LocalDate StartDate { get; }
        public LocalDate EndDateInclusive { get; }
        public LocalDate EndDateExclusive => EndDateInclusive.PlusDays(1);

        public ZonedDateTime ZoneStart => Zone.AtStartOfDay(StartDate);
        public ZonedDateTime ZoneEnd => Zone.AtStartOfDay(EndDateExclusive);

        public DateTime UtcStart => ZoneStart.ToDateTimeUtc();
        public DateTime UtcEnd => ZoneEnd.ToDateTimeUtc();

        public double HoursPerDay => IsTransitionDay ? (UtcEnd - UtcStart).TotalHours : 24;

        public int DaysInRange => IsTransitionDay ? 1 : (int)((ZoneStart - ZoneEnd).TotalDays);


        // -1 = Falling back DAY, +1 Spring Forward DAY, 0 means no transition occuring (Standard or DST).
        public int Transition => (State == DayState.FallBack) ? Backward : (State == DayState.SpringForward) ? Forward : None;
        public bool IsTransitionDay => (Transition != None);

        public const int Backward = -1;
        public const int Forward = 1;
        public const int None = 0;

        // internal constructor forces using static factory.
        internal ZonedDateRange(DateTimeZone zone, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, DayState state)
        {
            Zone = zone;
            StartDate = startDate;
            EndDateInclusive = endDate;
            State = state;
        }

        // A list should be fairly small.  Consider U.S. Central Time for an entire calendar year.  There will only be 5 items in the list.
        //      1) CST from Jan 1 to the day before Spring forward.
        //      2) Spring Forward transition day (one day is both start and end)
        //      3) CDT from day after Spring Forward and day before Fall Back.
        //      4) Fall Back transition day (again, only 1 day in range)
        //      5) CST after Fall Back day
        // The most important thing is that all days in a range will have the same length.
        // That way you can safely average in whatever that length is.

        public static IEnumerable<ZonedDateRange> GenerateRanges(DateTimeZone zone, Instant anchorInstant, int days)
        {
            if (zone == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(zone));
            }

            var anchorDate = anchorInstant.InZone(zone).Date;
            var inclusiveStartDate = (days < 0) ? anchorDate.PlusDays(days) : anchorDate;
            var inclusiveEndDate = (days < 0) ? anchorDate : anchorDate.PlusDays(days);

            return GenerateRanges(zone, inclusiveStartDate, inclusiveEndDate);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ZonedDateRange> GenerateRanges(DateTimeZone zone, LocalDate inclusiveStartDate, LocalDate inclusiveEndDate)
        {
            if (zone == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(zone));
            }

            // Small adjustment to add an extra day to the inclusive end date.
            // When working with LocalDate(s) that are inclusive, we obviously start at the start of the start date
            // BUT we want to end at the END of the end date, which is really the start of the next day following the
            // end date.
            var exclusiveEndDate = inclusiveEndDate.PlusDays(1);

            var startInstant = inclusiveStartDate.AtStartOfDayInZone(zone).ToInstant();
            var endInstant = exclusiveEndDate.AtStartOfDayInZone(zone).ToInstant();

            // Just in case the start or end day occurs on transition day, we pad each endpoint with a few days.
            // We will later prune away this padding.
            var pad = Duration.FromDays(5);
            var padStartInstant = startInstant.Minus(pad);
            var padEndInstant = endInstant.Plus(pad);

            var intervals = zone.GetZoneIntervals(padStartInstant, padEndInstant).ToList();

            // Take care of easy cases.
            // Check count returned instead of custom SupportsDaylightSavingsTime method.
            // E.g. Argentina supported DST in the past, but since 2010 has been on Standard time only.
            if (intervals.Count == 1)
            {
                yield return new ZonedDateRange(zone, inclusiveStartDate, exclusiveEndDate, DayState.Standard);
                yield break;
            }

            for (var index = 0; index < intervals.Count; index++)
            {
                var interval = ClampInterval(intervals[index], padStartInstant, padEndInstant);

                // Chop off the Start and End dates, since those are transition days.
                // That is move Start ahead 1 day, and move End back 1 day.
                var currStartDate = interval.Start.InZone(zone).Date.PlusDays(1);
                var currEndDate = interval.End.InZone(zone).Date.PlusDays(-1);

                var endLength = zone.HoursInDay(interval.End);

                var endState = DayState.Standard;
                if (endLength > NodaConstants.HoursPerDay)
                {
                    endState = DayState.FallBack;
                }
                else if (endLength < NodaConstants.HoursPerDay)
                {
                    endState = DayState.SpringForward;
                }

                var startState = (endState == DayState.FallBack) ? DayState.DST : DayState.Standard;
                var range = new ZonedDateRange(zone, LocalDate.Max(inclusiveStartDate, currStartDate), LocalDate.Min(exclusiveEndDate, currEndDate), startState);
                if (IsOkayToOutput(range))
                {
                    yield return range;
                }

                var endTransitionDate = interval.End.InZone(zone).Date;
                range = new ZonedDateRange(zone, endTransitionDate, endTransitionDate, endState);
                if (IsOkayToOutput(range))
                {
                    yield return range;
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool IsOkayToOutput(ZonedDateRange range) => (range.UtcEnd > range.UtcStart);

        private static ZoneInterval ClampInterval(ZoneInterval interval, Instant start, Instant end)
        {
            var outstart = start;
            var outend = end;

            if (interval.HasStart && outstart < interval.Start)
            {
                outstart = interval.Start;
            }

            if (interval.HasEnd && interval.End < outend)
            {
                outend = interval.End;
            }

            return new ZoneInterval(interval.Name, outstart, outend, interval.WallOffset, interval.Savings);
        }


        public override string ToString() => ToString(showZone: true);

        public string ToString(bool showZone)
        {
            var prefix = showZone ? $"{Zone}: " : "";
            return $"{prefix}{State,-13} [{UtcStart.ToIsoString()}, {UtcEnd.ToIsoString()}) {HoursPerDay}";
        }
    }
}
```

**Extensions.cs** 
previous methods are unchanged but FilterRanges was added.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NodaTime;

namespace NodaTime_Zoned_Ranges
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ZonedDateRange> FilterRanges(this IEnumerable<ZonedDateRange> ranges, LocalDate firstInclusiveDate, LocalDate lastInclusiveDate)
        {
            if (ranges == null || firstInclusiveDate > lastInclusiveDate)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            foreach (var range in ranges)
            {
                if (range.StartDate > lastInclusiveDate || range.EndDateInclusive < firstInclusiveDate)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                yield return new ZonedDateRange(range.Zone, LocalDate.Max(range.StartDate, firstInclusiveDate), LocalDate.Min(range.EndDateInclusive, lastInclusiveDate), range.State);
            }
        }

        // For DST Transition days, hours will be less than or greater than 24.
        public static double HoursInDay(this DateTimeZone zone, Instant instant)
        {
            if (zone == null)
            {
                return NodaConstants.HoursPerDay;
            }

            var day = instant.InZone(zone).LocalDateTime.Date;

            var bod = zone.AtStartOfDay(day);
            var eod = zone.AtStartOfDay(day.PlusDays(1));

            return (eod.ToInstant() - bod.ToInstant()).TotalHours;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Preferred format of ISO 8601 time string.  
        /// Unlike Round Trip format specifier of "o", this format will suppress decimal seconds
        /// if the input time does not have subseconds.
        /// </summary>
        public const string DateTimeExtendedIsoFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFK";


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an ISO-8601 compliant time string.  
        /// If the input Kind is Local and TimeZoneInfo.Local is not "UTC", then the output string will contain a time zone offset. 
        /// Unlike ToString("o"), if the input time does not contain subseconds, the output string will omit subseconds.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time">DateTime</param>
        /// <returns>String</returns>
        public static string ToIsoString(this DateTime time)
        {
            // TimeZoneInfo MUST use Equals method and not == operator.
            // Equals compares values where == compares object references.
            if (time.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local && TimeZoneInfo.Local.Equals(TimeZoneInfo.Utc))
            {
                // Don't use time zone offset if Local time is UTC
                time = DateTime.SpecifyKind(time, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
            return time.ToString(DateTimeExtendedIsoFormat);
        }

    }
}
```

**Program.cs**
Mostly unchanged except using the new ToString method.

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

namespace NodaTime_Zoned_Ranges
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var zoneIds = new string[] { "Central Brazilian Standard Time", "Singapore Standard Time" };

            var startDay = new LocalDate(2018, 1, 1);
            var endDay = new LocalDate(2019, 12, 31);

            foreach (var zoneId in zoneIds)
            {
                var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetZoneOrNull(zoneId);
                ZoneTest(zone, startDay, endDay);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress ENTER key");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ZoneTest(DateTimeZone zone, LocalDate startDay, LocalDate endDay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\n*** TEST FOR ZONE: {zone.Id} , Start:{startDay} , End:{endDay}\n");

            var startInstant = startDay.AtStartOfDayInZone(zone).ToInstant();
            var endInstant = endDay.PlusDays(1).AtStartOfDayInZone(zone).ToInstant();

            Console.WriteLine("NodaTime DateTimeZone.GetZoneIntervals");
            var intervals = zone.GetZoneIntervals(startInstant, endInstant);

            var i = 0;
            foreach (var interval in intervals)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  [{i++}]: {interval}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"\nCustom ZonedDateRange for {zone}");
            i = 0;
            var ranges = ZonedDateRange.GenerateRanges(zone, startDay, endDay);
            foreach (var range in ranges)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  [{i++}]: {range.ToString(showZone: false)}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ToString` method allow you to show or hide the Zone.  For the `DateTime` ranges, I use a trailing ")" to denote an exclusive endpoint, though there is a bug in NodaTime with Brazil and a handful of others zones with times ending in `59.999Z` that one would think should be inclusive.  I am keeping this behavior as-is and will wait for Jon to patch it one day in NodaTime.

**Sample Console Output**:

```
*** TEST FOR ZONE: Central Brazilian Standard Time , Start:Monday, January 1, 2018 , End:Tuesday, December 31, 2019

NodaTime DateTimeZone.GetZoneIntervals
  [0]: Central Brazilian Daylight Time: [2017-10-15T03:59:59Z, 2018-02-18T02:59:59Z) -03 (+01)
  [1]: Central Brazilian Standard Time: [2018-02-18T02:59:59Z, 2018-11-04T03:59:59Z) -04 (+00)
  [2]: Central Brazilian Daylight Time: [2018-11-04T03:59:59Z, 2019-02-17T03:00:00Z) -03 (+01)
  [3]: Central Brazilian Standard Time: [2019-02-17T03:00:00Z, EndOfTime) -04 (+00)

Custom ZonedDateRange for Central Brazilian Standard Time
  [0]: DST           [2018-01-01T03:00:00Z, 2018-02-17T03:00:00Z) 24
  [1]: FallBack      [2018-02-17T03:00:00Z, 2018-02-18T04:00:00Z) 25
  [2]: Standard      [2018-02-18T04:00:00Z, 2018-11-04T03:59:59.999Z) 24
  [3]: SpringForward [2018-11-04T03:59:59.999Z, 2018-11-05T03:00:00Z) 23.0000002777778
  [4]: DST           [2018-11-05T03:00:00Z, 2019-02-16T03:00:00Z) 24
  [5]: FallBack      [2019-02-16T03:00:00Z, 2019-02-17T04:00:00Z) 25
  [6]: Standard      [2019-02-17T04:00:00Z, 2020-01-02T04:00:00Z) 24
  [7]: Standard      [2020-01-06T04:00:00Z, 2020-01-07T04:00:00Z) 24


*** TEST FOR ZONE: Singapore Standard Time , Start:Monday, January 1, 2018 , End:Tuesday, December 31, 2019

NodaTime DateTimeZone.GetZoneIntervals
  [0]: Malay Peninsula Standard Time: [StartOfTime, EndOfTime) +08 (+00)

Custom ZonedDateRange for Singapore Standard Time
  [0]: Standard      [2017-12-31T16:00:00Z, 2020-01-01T16:00:00Z) 24
```